# NAT and iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I am new to iptables and NAT. But I am working on it through various material both in online and books. I have a doubt regarding NAT implementation using iptables.

Let us suppose my network scenario is as shown below.

```
                  linuxbox2 (10.0.0.3)
                    |
                    |
linuxbox1-------- Switch ----- INTERNET
(10.0.0.2)        (194.160.1.1)
```

My Linux boxes 1 & 2 connect to the internet via switch and I have only one Public IP-Address(194.160.1.1). But the communication is a bit strange. box2 does not connect directly to outerworld via switch. But it is in vlan with box1. Hence traffice from box2 goes to box1 then travels down to switch to connect to outer world. We does natting at box1

Since we try to masquerade to the same public ip-address what should be the rules in iptable.

My question might be strange but I am not able to explain it clealry ...

Started a new thread with more details and outputs at

[Iptables and SNAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/78237/iptables-and-snat)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you want to "differentiate the traffic originating from box 2 and 3 using nat table in box 1"? "what should be the rules in iptable which helps box1 in pre-routing the traffic to exact box" > it's taken care of automatically by netfilter which keeps track of which connections belongs to who.

Comment: Sorry folks I have done complete re-write of the question .... I am not sure if it is complete ... I might be updating even with more precise information once I am clear with my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, Box 2 is in a VLAN with Box 1, and Box 1 is in another VLAN as well which has access to the Internet.

Assuming the first VLAN is e.g. VLAN 100 and the second VLAN is VLAN 200, I assume you configured VLANs correctly on Box 1 and thus you have two network interfaces for the two VLANs (typically eth0.100 and eth0.200).

In this case the solution is simple, on Box 1:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0.200 -j MASQUERADE
```

With this command Box 1 will NAT-masquerade packets to the Internet on VLAN 200. Thus when Box 2 will send packets to Box 1 on VLAN 100, Box 1 will forward them to VLAN 200.

Make sure IP forwarding is enabled on Box 1 (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`).

Comment: @e-t172 I am very much thankful to u ...

Comment: One doubt ... When BOX2 and BOX1 try to do FTP to the same FTP server on INTERNET then how does the FTP server on internet differentiate BOX1 and BOX2 ... with the iptables rule which u have given for all the packets from both BOX1 and BOX2 we do POSTROUTING .. is that one rule enough ??? .. what about incoming packets destined to BOX1 and BOX2??

Comment: You just need the POSTROUTING rule. Netfilter will handle incoming packets automatically thanks to connection tracking.

Comment: "how does the FTP server on internet differentiate BOX1 and BOX2" It doesn't. The two boxes have the same public IP address, so the external server can't differentiate between the two, that's the whole point of masquerading. Box 1 takes care of which packets goes to which box.

Comment: @e-t172 can I have the same nat based rule just with the IP-Addresses I have given. These private ip-addresses are permanent but there is a chance of change in VLANS .... so is there any another where I can set a nat rule just through ipaddresses ??

Comment: With a simple command, no. You would have to write some shell code for that.

Comment: Can you help me with that shell script ??

Comment: You'd be better off learning to do that yourself. “Give someone a fish and you feed him for a day; teach someone to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.”

Comment: I got you but atleast tell the NOVICE some basic steps about  effective fishing so that he can enjoy the work he is doing. Similarly can you tell me basic way which I can write script for the problem I mentioned. I like to know a rough idea how that can be down with ip-address ... so that I can complete the script.

Comment: What I would probably do is extract the interface name from the IP address using the output of ifconfig, then use the name for the iptables rule. I recommend you read some shell scripting tutorials and HOWTOs.

Comment: Is using the interface name or mac-address so mandatory when we use NAT ?? ... cant we do directly using the IP-ADDRESS ??? ....

Comment: Now that I think of it, you could try this : "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE". This could have side effects, though.

Comment: Yeah for my situation can I try in this way "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.2/3 -j MASQUERADE"

But What is the need to give "MASQUERADE" when I know the public ip-address can't I simply replace the source address of the packet with the "Public IP-Address" ??

Can I know what would be the side effects for the solution you have given ??

Comment: You're absolutely right, you can use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE in your case. It is better suited to your situation but it won't solve your problem. Reguarding -s: this will have the side effect of altering ALL packets coming from 10.0.0.0/8, including those not forwarded to the Internet. You can add exceptions based on the destination using iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -d x.y.z.t/m -j RETURN but this will likely to become some unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Can i set the rule such a way that if I want to use internet for only FTP then create a rule saying iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p ftp  -s 10.0.0.2/3 -j SNAT --to 194.160.1.1

Now we can set the rule only for FTP and natting will be done only for FTP.

Comment: -p ftp won't work. -p is for select UDP or TCP. What you want to do is -p tcp --sport ftp. You will probably need another rule with -p tcp --sport ftp-data. Even then there is a probability this won't work very well because it is difficult to match FTP (random ports used for the actual data transfer).

Comment: By the way: "--to" -> "--to-source". And "10.0.0.2/3" is probably not what you want, the mask is way too large.

Comment: Yeah u r right .... then iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport ftp -m match iprange --src-range 10.0.0.2-3 -j SNAT --to-source 194.160.1.1

Comment: I made a mistake. It's obviously --dport, not --sport (destination port, not source port). My bad. However it is --sport for ftp-data. Aside from that this should work.

Comment: This gonna work then .. iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 21 -m match iprange --src-range 10.0.0.2-3 -j SNAT --to-source 194.160.1.1

Comment: It did not work really I have started a new thread on the same issue at http://serverfault.com/questions/78237/iptables-and-snat with more inputs ... hoping your reply down there ...